# Trying to find a product's weight from one table and show it agains that product on another table

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

I am blanking and getting frustrated so thought I would seek help.

In Excel, I would like to populate Sheet1 D2 with the correct weight.
To find it I would like to search Sheet 2 A:A for the code in Sheet1 A1 and return the value from the cell in the C:C from the match.

The result should mean Sheet 1 D2 = 6,334.72. A no match should return nil or 0.

I have tried Indexing with Match and I could not get a result other than NA or Value.

[Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3JQT.png)
[image]

[Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0ysb.png)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are talking about Sheet1 A2, not A1.

The formula at D2 is

```
=ifna(index('Sheet2'!$C:$C, match(A2,'Sheet2'!$A:$A,0)),0)
```

Also, please make sure the product codes on each worksheet are stored in the same format (numbers, perhaps). If one is number and another is text, you cannot get a match.

Comment: Yes you are correct A2 is what I am after. And that worked perfectly.  Thank you Oliver, you are a champion!